# MacOS Ventura 13.1: FortiClient SSL-VPN can't connect

Tags: macos, ssl, vpn

Recently I updated my Macbook to the latest macOS (Ventura 13.1). Before the update, I was able to use FortiClient to connect to a VPN. I am trying the same configuration with previous versions of macOS on another MacBook and I don't have the same problem.

The error message is:
[image]

I tried the following to resolve the issue:

1. Disabled my built-in firewall and restart the OS, but didn't work. Here I would like to highlight that I don't have other firewalls or antivirus installed.
2. The FortiClient has full access to Disk:
   [image]
   Again after restating the OS I have the same error
3. I found a post on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/fortinet/comments/ydls0g/forticlient_ems_not_working_on_latest_macos/#CommentTopMeta--Created--t1_ium8mh0) and I followed the instructions there, but again before/after restarting the OS I have the same error as before.

Since it stopped work after the update on Ventura 13.1 I think the root cause is the update and something related to the permission that I am missing.

The version of **FortiClient is 7.0.7.0245** which is the latest version of FortiClient.

Comment: Who runs the firewall mentioned in the first screenshot? Did you check with them whether they prohibit devices running Ventura?

Comment: I thought that maybe the Admin hasn't add the Ventura OS yet but I don't who runs the VPN :(